# i and not able to scroll side bar in selenium java

Tags: java, selenium, scroll

i was trying to do with eventfiringwebdriver but not able to use it showing unwanted errors

```
      EventFiringWebDriver EventFiringWebDriver = new EventFiringWebDriver(driver);
      
      EventFiringWebDriver.executeScript
```

("document.querySelector('/html/body/begin:/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div)')
;

```
second method i was trying  by javascript and actions
    JavascriptExecutor jre = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    jre.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,1000)");
    
    
    WebElement extension =  
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/begin:/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div"));
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    jre.executeScript("argument[2000].scrollIntoView();", extension);
```

Answer (score 0):

To path the WebElement as argument for js script evaluation next syntax should be used:

```
WebElement extension =  
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/begin:/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div"));
Thread.sleep(2000);
jre.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", extension);
```

`argument[2000]` changed to `arguments[0]`.

So, this command shouldn't throw errors any more.

---

**Args passing to JavascriptExecutor.executeScript**

This illustrates how to pass multiple args for evaluation, and why `arguments[0]` should be used for the case when we pass a single argument.

```
int result = jre.executeScript("return (arguments[0] + arguments[1] + arguments[2])", 2, 5, 10);
System.out.println("Result: " + result);
```

will print:

```
Result: 17
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JS to scroll to specific location on the page (top/bottom) or you can scroll to element.

```
public void scrollToTop() {
     jsExecutor.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0,0)");
}

public void scrollToBottom() {
     jsExecutor.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)");
}

public void scrollToOffset(int x, int y) {
     jsExecutor.executeScript("window.scrollTo(" + x + "," + (y - 100) + ")");
}
public void scrollToElement(WebElement webElement) {
     scrollToOffset(webElement.getLocation().x, webElement.getLocation().y);
}

public void scrollToElement(By locator) {
     scrollToTop();
     scrollToElement(findElement(locator));
}
```